# validation for divide by zero in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to perform calculator operation, depending on the input values and the operator the result should be displayed. I am struck with validation of dividing by 0 and I am not able to display the result in another function. Please someone could help me!

```
function calCaulation(e) {
var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
var z = document.getElementById("oper").value;
var a = "";

if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") || (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {
a = "Sum:Please enter the valid Number";
}
if (z == "/" && y == 0) {
a = "Divide By Zero Error";
}
return a;
} 
else {
var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value);
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value);
switch (z) {
case ("+"):
  a = "Sum:" + ((x + y).toFixed(2));
  break;
case ("-"):
  a = "Sub:" + ((x - y).toFixed(2));
  break;
case ("*"):
  a = "Mul:" + ((x * y).toFixed(2));
  break;
case ("/"):
  a = "Div:" + ((x / y).toFixed(2));
  break;
default:
  a = "Invalid Operator";
}
return a;
}
}
```

Comment: I see that there's a bracket after the `return a;` statement that actually closes the function

Comment: 1. Closing Flower Bracket  "{" before  else is invalid in your code.                                                        2. {var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value);
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value);} twice the assignment has been done unnecessarily.

Comment: empty strings are NaN. so `if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") || (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {` became `if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)) {`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bracket and `else` clause too much.

See here for a working jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/r2aq88tu/4/

**edit:** also, your return statement after the error checks would leave the function before the real code would execute, I moved the `return a` inside each `if` to make it work.

Your new code:

```
function calCaulation(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("oper").value;
    var a = "";

    if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") || (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {
        a = "Sum:Please enter the valid Number";
        return a;
    }
    if (z == "/" && y == 0) {
        a = "Divide By Zero Error";
        return a;
    }


    var x = parseFloat(x);
    var y = parseFloat(y);
    switch (z) {
        case ("+"):
            a = "Sum:" + ((x + y).toFixed(2));
            break;
        case ("-"):
            a = "Sub:" + ((x - y).toFixed(2));
            break;
        case ("*"):
            a = "Mul:" + ((x * y).toFixed(2));
            break;
        case ("/"):
            a = "Div:" + ((x / y).toFixed(2));
            break;
        default:
            a = "Invalid Operator";
    }
    return a;

}
```

Comment: Its actually not working, you can check out in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/2lFuVL9BKsrOWV6hiCRa?p=preview